# Create a hashvalue using a custom key and the algorithm ripemd160

Tags: python, ripemd

Here's the code I tried in Python but I get `AttributeError`:

```
>>> import hmac
>>> import hashlib
>>> h=hashlib.new('ripemd160')
>>> hmac.new("bedford","Hello",hashlib.ripemd160)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: module 'hashlib' has no attribute 'ripemd160'
```

I have searched the Python documentation and lots of forums but do not find much on ripemd160 and Python.

Answer (score 1):

`ripemd160` is not supported directly by the `hashlib` module:

> ```
> >>> hashlib.algorithms
> ```
>
> A tuple providing the names of the hash algorithms
>   guaranteed to be supported by this module.

The following are supported by the module: `md5, sha1, sha224, sha256, sha384, sha512`

So you need to use the `new` constructor again or pass the reference to the one you already created.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
hmac.new("bedford", "Hello", lambda: hashlib.new('ripemd160'))
```

or

```
h=hashlib.new('ripemd160')
hmac.new("bedford", "Hello", lambda: h)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the key needs to be binary (Python3) -> `b"bedford"`.

Then, the message needs to be encoded if it's unicode etc (Python3) -> `codecs.encode("Hello")`

Finally, use [`lambda` functions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
import codecs
import hmac
import hashlib
h=hashlib.new('ripemd160')
hmac.new(b"bedford", codecs.encode("Hello"), lambda: h)
```